# swipeWithEvent handler in SwiftUI

Tags: macos, swiftui, trackpad

I'd like to handle swipe events in my mac SwiftUI app. Normally I would override `swipeWithEvent` but it doesn't look like I can do that from within a SwiftUI view? How do I subscribe to these events?

Comment: Use DragGesture to corresponding view.

Comment: DragGesture works for click and dragging with the mouse but not for swiping with the trackpad. Is there a way to make it work for both?

Comment: Look at `@GestureState` if you want to jack into the gesture's events
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/gesturestate


Here's some sample code
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/what-is-the-gesturestate-property-wrapper